# Type conflict of maxloc in Fortran

Tags: fortran, rank

I have the following Fortran program

```
PROGRAM main

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER                          :: i
  INTEGER,dimension(:),allocatable :: x0

  allocate(x0(1:25))
  DO i=1,25
     x0(i)=i
  END DO

  print*,"maxloc de x0 est 25, en effet",maxloc(x0)

  print*,"Cinq fois maxloc(x0)",INT(maxloc(x0))

  print*,"f applique a la fonction",f(maxloc(x0))

  print*,"f1 applique a la fonction",f1(INT(maxloc(x0)))

  CONTAINS

  FUNCTION f(maxlocec)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    !Entrées
    INTEGER,dimension(1) :: maxlocec
    !Sorties
    INTEGER,dimension(1) :: f

    f=maxlocec**2

  END FUNCTION f

  FUNCTION f1(maxlocec)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    !Entrées
    INTEGER :: maxlocec
    !Sorties
    INTEGER :: f1

    f1=maxlocec**2

  END FUNCTION f1

END PROGRAM
```

when I execute it i get the following error message:

```
print*,"f1 applique a la fonction",f1(INT(maxloc(x0)))
                                        1
Error: Rank mismatch in argument 'maxlocec' at (1) (0 and 1)
```

I have tried `f1(maxloc(x0))` and it was not working, so I thought `f1(INT(maxloc(x0)))` would work and it is not.

The output of `maxloc` seems to be an integer but is not. What it is the way to solve it?

Comment: Do you understand that an array with one element is not the same thing as a scalar?

Comment: Note also that the error is about a _rank mismatch_ not a type conflict, and it's a compile-time error not run-time.  Perhaps you could edit the question/title if you understand the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maxloc routine does not return a scalar integer but, in this case, a 1-dimensional integer array of size 1.
From the standard:

> MAXLOC (ARRAY, DIM [, MASK, KIND, BACK]) or
> MAXLOC (ARRAY [, MASK, KIND, BACK])
>
> ...
>
> Result Characteristics. Integer. If KIND is present, the kind type
> parameter is that specified by the value of KIND; otherwise the kind
> type parameter is that of default integer type. If DIM does not
> appear, the result is an array of rank one and of size equal to the
> rank of ARRAY; otherwise, the result is of rank n − 1 and shape [d1,
> d2, . . . , dDIM−1, dDIM+1, . . . , dn], where [d1, d2, . . . , dn] is
> the shape of ARRAY.

So in your case yo will probably need:

```
print*,"f1 applique a la fonction",f1(maxloc(x0,1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much !
Have a nice day :)